# How to change the default logo size in the OpenChurch theme?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to upload an image for the logo with a slightly higher resolution than the default logo, but I don't find any way to change the default logo size in the [OpenChurch theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/openchurch_theme). I don't need the text beside the logo there, but I need a bigger logo.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Admin toolbar, click on appearance, then click on settings.

[image]

Scroll down to **LOGO IMAGE SETTINGS** and ***uncheck*** `Use the default logo supplied by the theme` and upload your own logo.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed instructions with screenshots. If I upload my logo there which is bigger in dimensions(200x150), it is scaled back to smaller(60x45) resolution. Anyway to keep the resolution intact? I checked the css file with inspect element at /profiles/openchurch/themes/openchurch_theme/css/openchurch-style.css but get where to change the resolution since they have not added height and width there.

Comment: @yogi then try adding `.site-branding__logo img{ height: 200; width: 150px; }` to your css file and clear/flush the cache to see changes.